# Is it possible to view the contents of a serialized hashmap in unix

Tags: java, unix, data-structures

I have used objectstream and serialized a hashmap into a file on Unix. Is it possible to view the contents of this serialized file using some command/tool without having to again write another code to load it using objectstream?

Comment: `cat`, `more` have you tried?

Comment: You can open the file with any editor available on the system. Vi is pretty much guaranteed, possibly you may also have emacs. You could also `more` the file, or heck, `cat` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can view it using any standard Unix tool. However, what you'll see is a binary file and not a comprehensible hashmap. To see the latter you'll have to write some Java code.